# Detecting the mode of the exercise package

Tags: package-options, exercises

I am trying to detect whether the exercise package's option ***noanswer*** is on, with the intention of not displaying parts in either mode.

Here is my mwe:

---

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[noaswer]{exercise}

\newif\ifpaper
\newif\ifmemo
\paperfalse
\memofalse

\makeatletter%
\@ifpackagewith{excercise}{noanswer}{%
\papertrue%
}{%
\memotrue%
}%
\makeatother%

\begin{document}
\ifpaper
paper
\fi

\ifmemo
memo
\fi

\end{document}
```

With this I always get memo, whether ***noanswer*** is provided or not.

---

1. Is there something I'm missing?
2. Or there another approach to ensure the correct detection?

Comment: Does changing `\@ifpackagewith{excercise}{noanswer}` to `\@ifpackagewith{exercise}{noanswer}` help?

Comment: Yes it does! I don't know why I did not check for something as simple as that!

Comment: Glad it helps.  I'm voting to close the question as *Too Localized* since it's not likely to come up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `exercise` knows several options that disable the answers: `noanswer`, `exerciseonly`; and `outputnothing` also disables exercise output. Internally the packages uses switches: `\if@AnswerOutput` for answers and `\if@ExerciseOutput` for exercises. Thus the first switch provides an alternative to checking the option using `\@ifpackagewith`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[noanswer]{exercise}

\newif\ifpaper
\newif\ifmemo
\paperfalse
\memofalse

\makeatletter
\if@AnswerOutput
  \memotrue
\else
  \papertrue
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ifpaper
paper
\fi

\ifmemo
memo
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will definitely use it.  The original problem was as @Matthew Leingang pointed out a simple typo!